# Create column based on date and time conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of daily smartcard transactions for a transit agency with over 10,000 records. I'm trying to create a column called `transfer` that indicates whether the transaction was a transfer or not. I have created a mock data set:

```
mock_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cardNumber': ['100', '100', '100', '200', '300', '300', '300'],
    'type': ['DAILY_CAP_REACHED', 'DAILY_CAP_REACHED', 'DAILY_CAP_REACHED', 'DAILY_CAP_REACHED',
             'DAILY_CAP_REACHED', 'DAILY_CAP_REACHED', 'DAILY_CAP_REACHED'],
    'date_only': ['2021/05/01', '2021/05/01', '2021/05/01', '2021/05/01', '2021/05/04', '2021/05/04', '2021/05/04'],
    'time_only': ['17:15', '17:45', '18:15', '12:15', '13:15', '17:45', '18:15'],
    'fare': [250, 0, 0, 250, 250, 0, 0]
})
```

Which produces the following table.

```
    cardNumber  type                date_only   time_only   fare
0   100         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/01  17:15       250
1   100         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/01  17:45       0
2   100         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/01  18:15       0
3   200         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/01  12:15       250
4   300         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/04  13:15       250
5   300         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/04  17:45       0
6   300         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/04  18:15       0
```

Each day passengers have a 90 minute window to make a transfer from their first transaction. So if more than 90 minutes have passed since their first transaction, it should not be recorded as a transfer.
I'm hoping to have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
    cardNumber  type                date_only   time_only   fare   transfer
0   100         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/01  17:15       250    N
1   100         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/01  17:45       0      Y
2   100         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/01  18:15       0      Y
3   200         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/01  12:15       250    N
4   300         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/04  13:15       250    N
5   300         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/04  17:45       0      N
6   300         DAILY_CAP_REACHED   2021/05/04  18:15       0      Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
mock_df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(mock_df['date_only'] + ' ' + mock_df['time_only'])

mock_df['transfer'] = np.where(mock_df.groupby('cardNumber')['datetime'].diff() <= pd.Timedelta(minutes=90), 'Y', 'N')
```

**Result:**

```
print(mock_df)

  cardNumber               type   date_only time_only  fare            datetime transfer
0        100  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/01     17:15   250 2021-05-01 17:15:00        N
1        100  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/01     17:45     0 2021-05-01 17:45:00        Y
2        100  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/01     18:15     0 2021-05-01 18:15:00        Y
3        200  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/01     12:15   250 2021-05-01 12:15:00        N
4        300  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/04     13:15   250 2021-05-04 13:15:00        N
5        300  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/04     17:45     0 2021-05-04 17:45:00        N
6        300  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/04     18:15     0 2021-05-04 18:15:00        Y
```

Comment: @HenryEcker  I also had the puzzle of same question as you.  But by looking at the last row of expected output, you know that every transaction of the same card is treated just the same as a new transaction and the time limit of 90 minutes interval is reset.  Otherwise, the last row won't be flagged `Y'`.

Comment: I've run this on my full data set and I'm still doing some exploring but it appears that everything has been calculated correctly. In fact, it has helped me uncover a few transactions that have 95 minutes between them and the system has coded them as transfers but the logic introduced by SeaBean has coded them as non-transfers.

Comment: @miguelf88  That's good my logics help your processing.   One thing want to clarify with you, just for the sake of knowing more about the nature of your business.  The question is:  Is it that the business nature treat every transaction as a new one and the 90 minutes interval counted from the last transaction ?  In this way, we count transfer relative to the last transaction, is this correct ?

Comment: @HenryEcker  Based on OP's positive confirmation of the full set data checking outcome, I think our interpretation is correct.  Anyway, I asked OP for clarification.  Let's see the reply.

Comment: @SeaBean, If I understand your question, you are correct. Say a passenger's first transaction is at 9:00 am. They then board again at 9:30 am. This second transaction is a transfer because it was less than 90 minutes after their first transaction. Now, if the passenger did not board at 9:30 am and instead their second transaction was at 11:00 am, we would not consider that a transfer.

Comment: So for the 3 transactions at 13:15, 17:45, and 18:15, we treat the last as a transfer because 17:45 to 18:15 is within 90 minutes ?   We are not counting the interval between 13:15 and 18:15, right ?

Comment: Card `300` boards at 13:15 and then boards at 17:45. This is not a transfer because of the amount of time between the two transactions. However, the 18:15 transaction is a transfer because of the transaction 30 minutes before at 17:45.

Answer (score 0):

The key piece I'm reading is this requirement:

"If more than 90 minutes have passed since their first transaction, it should not be recorded as a transfer."

Because of this, comparing only to the previous time will not suffice, as there could be less than 90 minutes between each of 3 transactions, but more than 90 minutes between the first and the last, making it a non-transfer.

This approach will work, albeit there may be a way to make it a bit prettier:

```py
mock_df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(mock_df['date_only'] + ' ' + mock_df['time_only'])
for grp_idx,grp in mock_df.groupby('cardNumber'):
    for i,(idx,dt) in enumerate(grp['datetime'].iteritems()):
        if i==0:
            dt_comp = dt
            mock_df.at[idx,'transfer'] = 'N'
        else:
            if dt-dt_comp < pd.Timedelta(minutes=90):
                mock_df.at[idx,'transfer'] = 'Y'
            else:
                mock_df.at[idx,'transfer'] = 'N'
                dt_comp = dt
```

edit: add results

```py
  cardNumber               type   date_only time_only  fare  \
0        100  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/01     17:15   250   
1        100  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/01     17:45     0   
2        100  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/01     18:15     0   
3        200  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/01     12:15   250   
4        300  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/04     13:15   250   
5        300  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/04     17:45     0   
6        300  DAILY_CAP_REACHED  2021/05/04     18:15     0   

             datetime transfer  
0 2021-05-01 17:15:00        N  
1 2021-05-01 17:45:00        Y  
2 2021-05-01 18:15:00        Y  
3 2021-05-01 12:15:00        N  
4 2021-05-04 13:15:00        N  
5 2021-05-04 17:45:00        N  
6 2021-05-04 18:15:00        Y
```